# How to apply SOAP in FedEx sample code?

Tags: c#, fedex

I downloaded both sample code and WSDL files on the website.

I checked that there are some text documents inside of WSDL folder.

It was based on SOAP, but I don't know how to apply.

How do I apply for SOAP file in the sample code?

It seems like the example queries.

Could you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

you actually do not want to think about the other files in that same folder where your WSDL is located. Just add a Web Reference to your project and direct it to your WSDL. This should add a reference to your project under which you will see all these other files. WSDL will automatically refer those files when needed.